# Only dropbox.com isn't resolving on my laptop. How do I fix it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dns, dropbox

OS: Windows 10 20H2

Dropbox.com isn't resolving. I cannot connect to it using my laptop. I have tried the following methods:

1. Disable the firewall
2. Different browsers (Chrome, Edge and Firefox)
3. Reset Network in Windows.
4. Change DNS to both Google and CloudFlare; neither worked.
5. Use a VPN
6. Reset Chrome / clear cookies and cache
7. Flush DNS record

The website is up and running though. I can connect to it using my Android phone that is connected to the same WiFi as my laptop. However it doesn't load on my laptop. I have tried all these methods so far. Every other website is loading perfectly fine.

Can someone please tell me how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `hosts` file. On Windows it's located in `C:\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. It's a regular text file, but you'll need administrative privileges to edit it. You can run Notepad as administrator first and then paste the path into its *Open* window.

If there's a `0.0.0.0 dropbox.com` line or similar (different numbers), remove it. Save changes and reboot just to be sure.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.

Comment: +1 was also my first thought. :)